# use vue to enable disable record in blade template

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I am brand new to vue js.

I have a blade view that returns a list of modules, one of the columns has a button that will enable or disable the module via an ajax call.

I would like to use VUE js  to achieve this.

This is what I have so far

```
<div class="content">
   <table id="moduleTable">
      <tr>
         <th>Module Name</th>
         <th>Status</th>
         <th>Update</th>
      </tr>
      @foreach($modules as $module)
      <tr>
         <td >{{$module->name}}</td>
         @if($module->enabled())
         <td>Enabled</td>
         <td><button @click="toggleModule('{{$module->name}}')" >Disable</button></td>
         @else
         <td>Disabled</td>
         <td><button @click="toggleModule('{{$module->name}}')">Enable</button></td>
         @endif
      </tr>
      @endforeach
   </table>
</div>
```

and this is what I have for my js

```
var buttons = new Vue({
    el: '#moduleTable',
    data:  {}
    ,
    methods: {
        toggleModule: function (moduleName) {
                console.log(moduleName);
        }
    }
});
```

But now I am not sure what to do next (I understand the axios bit to make the call).

I want to be able to toggle the the text of the button enable/disable, so how do I get a reference to the button that has been clicked?

Also am I passing the module value to the click event correctly or is there a better way?

Comment: i think you have to use v-for and modules array  in vue data if you want to change module status on ajax call so that you can change it dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can make a Vue component called `'<module>'` and then and then use the directive and then combine the blade foreach to make a `'<module>'` component foreach module identified with a `v-key`.

Example:

```
@foreach($modules as $module)
  <module v-key="{{$module->id}}" name="{{$module->name}}" is-enabled="{{$module->enabled()}}"> 
@endforeach
```

Then inside the `'<module>'` component u can use the `v-if` of `v-show` to enable or disable each component.

here is a link for the documentation on Conditional Rendering:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
<div class="content">
   <table id="moduleTable">
      <tr>
         <th>Module Name</th>
         <th>Status</th>
         <th>Update</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="(module,index) in modules">
         <td >@{{module.name}}</td>
         <td><span v-if="module.enabled"> Enabled
         <span v-else>Disabled</span></td>
         <td><span v-if="module.enabled"><button @click="toggleModule(module.name,index)">Disable</button></span>
            <span v-else><button @click="toggleModule(module.name,index)">Disable</button></span>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>

var buttons = new Vue({
    el: '#moduleTable',
    data:  {
        modules:{{ $modules}}
    },
    methods: {
        toggleModule: function (moduleName,index) {
            var self = this;
               axios.post('url',{'name':moduleName})
               .then(response){
                   self.modules[index].enabled = false; // false true whatever
               }
        }
    }
});
```